# got unexpected value in TDS response at offset:0

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm using JDBC Driver Version 1.2.2828.100 and Database Sql Server 2008 R2.

I'm doing search operation by joining three tables containing 1,40,000 rows

SELECT USERID, USERLOGIN, DOMAIN FROM USER (nolock), USER01 (nolock), DOMAIN (nolock) WHERE USERLASTNAME= "aa" AND USERFIRSTNAME = "bb"  AND USERDOMAINID = DOMAINID AND USERID = USER01ID  ORDER BY USERID

I'm getting the below Error and my application crashes immediately

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader throwInvalidTDS
SEVERE: TDSReader@d5ccfa ( ConnectionID:11 TransactionID:0x0000000000000000) got unexpected value in TDS response at offset:0

What does the TDS reponse at offset:0 refers ? 
How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, TDS is tabular data stream.  It is how the client (machine) talks to the database (server).  You are using the microsoft jdbc driver.

Here are some things to improve your code and fix the problem.

1 - Please use ANSI 20xx standards.

That means the query will be re-written as the following.

```
-- Updated using newer syntax
SELECT 
    U0.USERID, 
    U0.USERLOGIN, 
    D0.DOMAIN 
FROM 
    USER as U0 with (nolock) INNER JOIN 
    USER01 as U1 with (nolock) ON U0.USERID = U1.USER01ID  INNER JOIN 
    DOMAIN as D0 with (nolock) U0.USERDOMAINID  = D0.DOMAINID 
WHERE 
    U0.USERLASTNAME= "aa" AND 
    U0.USERFIRSTNAME = "bb" 
ORDER BY 
    U0.USERID
```

I no not advocate the (nolock) but that is a whole different battle.

2 - Next, look at this article.  The user found out that a type case was causing the issue.  Make sure the data types are compatible with JAVA.
http://adrielservice.com/blog/?p=362

I hope this helps.

John

Comment: Thanks John. I have changed my query as well as i have cross checked the type case also. Still the problem Exist. When i tries to execute the same query multiple times say(3 to 5 times in a minute) i get this error. Am planning to change the driver and check.

Comment: Just an idea, but try runinig the query through MS Query, if it still exists in your version of office.  You can use the native client driver or ODBC.  Use the query above.  If it works, it is definitely a driver 2 Java issue.  Good luck

Comment: I re-read you response.  So you are executing the query 3 to 5 times a minute.  Is this a single process?  Do you have alerting for blocking or deadlocks in place?  I am wondering if you are having a concurrency issue.  Set IO statistics and TIME on.  How long does the query take?  Are you using a good query plan.  Just some things to investigate if the driver upgrade does not fix the issue.